# How to desearialize from json.net to class type in single method?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have two classes Person and Bird with some properties and Both are implementiing to `IObjectType` which is just any empty interface used to make person and bird of same type. I have their corrosponding .json files in disk. I want to write method to deseiralize json file and return corrosponding type without any if else condition using json.net. something like below

```
public static IObjectType ConvertJsonToClass(string jsonString)
{
    //This line map json to person<br/>
    Person personObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<personObj>(jsonString);

    return personObj;
}
```

How can I make the above code generic to convert it for Bird class. Feels like I should be using generics but how and where?

Comment: Why don´t you want an `if-else`statement? If you don´t know the actual time at compile-time you have to speicify it based on some conditions, so you´ll have to write a similar statement however.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Generic Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx).

**Usage:**

```
var myBird = ConvertJsonToClass<Bird>(jsonString);
```

**Code:**

```
public static IObjectType ConvertJsonToClass<T>(string jsonString) where T : IObjectType
{
    T obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But at compile time it's asking for explicit converison of T to IObjectType .

Comment: @ChakreshSingh, Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Json.Net cannot figure out the type simply by reading the JSON.
You have to specify the type (ex. by generic implementations as others suggested) or store the type inside the JSON:

I would recommend to have both Bird and Person derive from base class that would indicate the type:

```
public static BaseObject ConvertJsonToClass<T>(string jsonString)
{
    BaseObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseObject>(jsonString);
    switch (obj.TypeEnum)
    {
        case ObjectTypeEnum.Bird:
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bird>(jsonString);
            break;
        case ObjectTypeEnum.Person:
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(jsonString);
            break;
    }
    return obj;
}
public class BaseObject
{
    public ObjectTypeEnum TypeEnum { get; set; }
}
public enum ObjectTypeEnum
{
    Person = 1,
    Bird = 2
}

public class Person : BaseObject
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    private Person()
    {
        TypeEnum = ObjectTypeEnum.Person;
    }
}
public class Bird : BaseObject
{
    public double Weight { get; set; }

    private Bird()
    {
        TypeEnum = ObjectTypeEnum.Bird;
    }


}
```

Comment: Where is this different from an `if-else`-statement that OP wanted to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something:

```
public static IObjectType ConvertJsonToClass(string jsonString)
{
  IObjectType obj;
  try{
    obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(jsonString);
  }
  catch{
    try{
      obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bird>(jsonString);
    }
    catch{ obj = null; }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Throwing exceptions to handle program-flow is considered bad practice. Exceptions should represent real BAD unexpected bahaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static IObjectType ConvertJsonToClass<T>(string jsonString)
{
    IObjectType obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString) as IObjectType;
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: You may also add some constraint on `T` to `IObjectType`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic type `T`, and then constrain `T` to be a subtype of `IObjectType`.

```
public static T ConvertJsonToClass<T>(string jsonString) where T : IObjectType 
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
}

var person = ConvertJsonToClass<Person>(json);
var bird = ConvertJsonToClass<Bird>(json);
```